# Fetch multiple keys from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary: `d`

Is there a way to fetch multiple values of keys from dictionary.

Example:

```
d = {1:1, 2:2, 4:4}
keys = [1,2,3]
k_v_pairs = multi_key_fetch(d, keys) --> returns {1:1, 2:2}
```

I am hoping not to loop thru the dictionary and search one key at a time? 
So, was wondering if there is a dictionary implementation in python, which helps in retrieving multiple keys in one shot from a dictionary and also tells us which keys are "hit" and "missed"?

Comment: Always did that with comprehension but this way if possible would be great to know